# Algorithm: Finding max subset of elements in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array `arr` containing pairs of elements. I need to find the largest subset from that array, such that, each pair wise element in that subset exists in the array `arr`.

e.g. let `arr = [(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,d)]`
Then, the largest subset would be `{a,b,d}`, because all possible pair-wise combinations in the subset exists in `arr`.

Comment: What if there's a loop? Consider `[(a,b), (b,d), (d, c), (c,a)]`

Comment: What's the point on this? What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @erip there won't be any duplicates, i.e. both (a,b) and (b,a) won't be in the array.

Comment: @Kriggs the pairs of elements that exist in the array satisfy a condition (have intersection <> null), my goal is to find the largest combination of elements that satisfy this condition (intersection <> null).

Comment: @SaadH array size ? all the items will be lower case english letters ?

Comment: [Maximum clique problem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the problem of finding the largest complete component (maximum clique problem) in an undirected graph, where each pair represents an edge in the graph.

This problem is NP-hard, so there's no better approach than a simple brute-force-search. The implementation is either trivial or too complex to be posted here though, so you'll have to figure that out on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your input, will have a look at that. Also, is finding just the size of the subset also NP-hard? e.g. There maybe multiple combinations of (largest) subset possible, but I am more interested in finding the size of that subset.

Comment: that'll be NP-hard aswell